# Automatic binding to some service properties in Catel with Fody

Tags: catel, fody, fody-propertychanged

Assuming there is some service:

```
public interface IDeviceManagerService
{
    ISomeDeviceApi Api { get; }
}
```

It's purpose is to monitor external environment (USB, network, etc.), instantiate device API when the device detected and make property `null` when the device is no longer available.

Supposing there is a **view model** with this service injected, I would like to have change notifications for `IDeviceManagerService.Api` to make things like below possible (for example, having the button which is only active when the device API is available).

```
private Boolean OnSomeCommandCanExecute()
{
    return _deviceManagerService.Api != null;
}
```

I wonder if there is a clean way to make this work without manual change notifications handling (with Catel.Fody or PropertyChanged.Fody). So far I have managed to get working result by making service implementation derived from `ModelBase`, registering it's injected instance as a `[Model]` inside the view model and exposing it's `Api` property using `[ViewModelToModel]` attribute, but this is very dirty way.

Is there some common approach or It would be better to go with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and use notifications [wrapper](http://docs.catelproject.com/vnext/catel-core/preventing-memory-leaks/change-notification-wrapper/) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most approaches, services don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged (they are not models), so my recommendation is to add manual events:

```
public interface IDeviceManagerService
{
    ISomeDeviceApi Api { get; }

    event EventHandler<DeviceApiEventArgs> ApiChanged;
}
```

This way you can deal with the stuff you are interested in (subscribe in InitializeAsync, unsubscribe in CloseAsync).

Comment: Ok, it seems that a more explicit and simple way will be better, thanks.